# Cannot access the internet while i debug android on device

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to develop an android application that uses network connection. The server is up and running, but when i am trying to access it from the device that runs the android app (in debug mode-using eclipse) it outputs a message that 'cannot find the server' after a UnknownHostException occurs!
 I have tested the server with a java application and it works fine! What is the problem then with the device?

Comment: Does the browser on the device resolve the address correctly?

Comment: actually it didn't!! I had no Wi-Fi access at that time, then fixed it and it worked!

Comment: was it running independently , i.e. if you don't debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your Mainfest.xml file for this line...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```